Text Flickering and rendering issues, wrong colours and symbols
I have a very wired problem. Some applications don't show fonts correctly for the past few days. Mainly Firefox and Thunderbird are affected (both are snaps), but also the header of some other application windows have problems.
I find it hard to describe what is happening. Sometimes text gets invisible, sometimes it appears in random colors and sometimes it displays wrong characters. One example is in the screenshot below.

What I have tried so far:

Disable hardware acceleration in Firefox (made it a little better I guess)
Update Firefox (no effect)
Update all system packages (no effect)
Reboot (no effect)
Delete an regenerate Font Cache (no effect)
Test a Ubuntu live USB, which had the same problem

I'm very unsure how to further debug this issue as I can't tell where it is originating from. I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 on a 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-12700H with NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Graphics (On demand Mode) and Linux 6.8.0-40-generic kernel.
I'm very thankful for any suggestions, otherwise I will have to refresh my whole system.
Update
I wanted to reinstall my os, but using a fresh live USB (both Ubuntu and Fedora), the same problem occurred. So it seems to be a hardware issue. Disabling the integrated GPU and only using the discrete NVIDIA GPU solves the issue.

You have asked a graphics question but have failed to give the graphics info. What is the model of the graphics card? Please update the question and add this info, not as a comment.

Maybe this could help, it happened to me when i upgraded from ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 but couldn't find a solution so i just did a fresh install.
